# Grub not booting up

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

Hey guys I have a question about grub.

I am trying to dualboot windows7 and linux however I am recving a problem with grub. It will just boot into windows. 
I also delated the system reserved partioton because of hopeless.

I tried to use grubrescue tool and it says this

```
GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again.
```

The paste that it gives me for help is this.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/11508445/

I have plenty of unlocated space so I dont see why it is telling me this. Any help?

Comment: In addition to the gpt errors, did you delete sda1 which has the Windows boot files and move boot flag (Windows active partition) to the Linux partition. Grub does not use boot flag, but Windows has to have the boot flag on the primary NTFS partition which has bootmgr & BCD. You show neither of those files. You can move boot flag back to sda2 and repair it with the Windows repair console, or recovery sda1 and set it as bootable and repair it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem (from your Boot Repair output):

```
Warning: /dev/sda contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT table.
However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it should.
Perhaps it was corrupted -- possibly by a program that doesn't understand GPT
partition tables.  Or perhaps you deleted the GPT table, and are now using an
msdos partition table.  Is this a GPT partition table?
```

It looks like your disk used GPT at one point, but when you (re-)installed Windows, you did so in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. That often results in leftover GPT data, which tends to confuse libparted-based tools, resulting in various errors and problems.

The simplest and safest solution is to use my [FixParts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) tool (command name: `fixparts`), which is part of the `gdisk` package in Ubuntu. The referenced page provides details, but in brief, launching FixParts on the disk should cause it to ask if you want to delete the leftover GPT data. Confirm that deletion and then quit from the program.